# Numpy square return wrong values for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, square

I have a data set where pairs of numbers are represented by 32 bits, each number is represented as two 8 unsigned integers.

I'm trying to get the first real part in one array and the complex part in a second array. 
I'm then trying to square each part, add them up and take the square root of the sum. (aka taking the magnitude).
When I try squaring the elements of each arrays using numpy.square I get not only negative but also inaccurate values. 
Any idea what's going on/what's wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

data = np.fromfile(r'C:\Users\Miaou\Desktop\RAW_DATA_000066_000008.bin', dtype="int16")

print(data)

Is = data[0::2]
Qs = data[1::2]
Is_square = np.square(Is, dtype='int16')
Qs_square = np.square(Qs, dtype='int16')

print('Is',Is)
print('Qs',Qs)
print('Is square',Is_square)
print('Qs square',Qs_square)

Output: Is [  335  -720  8294 ... -3377  3878  6759]
Qs [-2735  4047  1274 ...  -279  1319  4918]
Is square [-18847  -5888 -22364 ...    865  31140   5489]
Qs square [  9121  -5791 -15324 ...  12305 -29711   3940]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). The min value of the `int16` (signed) type is `-32768` and the maximum value is `32767`. The reason for this is because you only have 16 bits (that's what `int16`) means. Note that `2^16 = 65536`, but since it's signed (negatives allowed), we don't have values `0` through `65536`, but instead you can imagine they are shifted down such that `0` is centered (i.e. `-32768` to `32767`)

Let's take your first element of the `Is` as an example:

```
>>> 335**2
112225
```

Note that `112225 > 32767`. This means you'll get overflow. It just keeps wrapping around until it lands in the valid range:

```
>>> x = 112225
>>> x = x - 2**16
>>> x
46689 # Still not in the valid range. Repeat.
>>> x = x - 2**16
>>> x
-18847 # Yep, now we are between -32768 and 32768
```

The other answer here is not quite right as leaving off the dtype does not suffice:

```
>>> Is = np.array([335, -720, 8294, -3377, 3878, 6759]).astype('int16')
>>> Is
array([  335,  -720,  8294, -3377,  3878,  6759], dtype=int16)
>>> Is_sq_nodtype = np.square(Is)
>>> Is_sq_nodtype
array([-18847,  -5888, -22364,    865,  31140,   5489], dtype=int16)
```

`numpy` ops keep the same dtype. You actually need to "up" the dtype to have more bits. `int32` should probably do the trick for your values (you can also do `int64` or `float` depending on how big your values are, here is a list of dtypes: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.types.html)

Working example:

```
>>> Is = np.array([335, -720, 8294, -3377, 3878, 6759]).astype('int16')
array([  335,  -720,  8294, -3377,  3878,  6759], dtype=int16)
>>> Is_sq = np.square(Is, dtype='int32')
>>> Is_sq
array([  112225,   518400, 68790436, 11404129, 15038884, 45684081], dtype=int32)
```

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

Remove dtype='int16' from your np.square() calls.

Comment: I didn't have this originally and I was getting the same issue. That was an attempt at trouble shooting it!